# cargar contenido html con ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando cargar varios sitios de mi pagina sin tener que recargar la pagina cada que me muevo de un sitio a otro, (sin usar las eiquetas href).

este es mi codigo js ajax:

```
$('#ir-pagina2').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vistas/modulos/ajax.pagina2.php",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#div-results-piku').html(response);
        }
    });
```

este es mi archivo ajax:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../../index2.php";

//aqui todo el contenido html, que necesito.
?>
```

Me carga el contenido sin problemas hasta ahora, pero el problema es que me lo pinta debajo del que ya habia anteriormente, y necesito que el contenido que se va a cargar reemplace al que esta cargado.

Comment: Deberia reemplazarte todo el contenido de `div-results-piku` usando el `html`, intenta hacer un `remove()` antes y luego asignalo denuevo

Comment: Parece que el contenido que existe al cargar la página no está en el mismo elemento en el que estás insertando el contenido obtenido por AJAX.

Comment: si tueve que envolver todo el contenido a reemplazar en un div con el id="div-results-piku" , y en pocas palabras estaria moviendome de un sitio a otro de forma dinamica.